# HP ProCurve switch 2848 J4904A

Tags: hp-procurve

1. How to configure a local password security for the switch, can it be accessible with a default password?
2. Can the web browser interface password be deleted?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: This was sorted thank you, the switch was set to factory default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two levels of access, **Manager** and **Operator**.
You can do this first via the web interface.
Also you can disable web access by **no web-management** in CLI or by setting Web Agent Enabled parameter to No via we-management.

Please take a look at this file:
http://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/59906023-1004-Management-Guide.pdf

Comment: Thank you Moghaddas.

I have tried to get to web console but i am prompted for user name and password as much as i do not know them, how can i get in the console without having to set factory default settings?

Comment: If you have a password already set on this switch, and you have physical access to the switch, 
press and hold the Clear button (on the front of the switch) for a minimum of one second to clear all password protection.
ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/Security-Oct2005-59906024-Chap02-Passwords.pdf

Comment: Before i do that is it going to clear password protection only or is it going to clear everything on the switch, Such as the IP and the Mac?


And for the Password i haven't set any as the switch was configured long time ago.